# JSON Decode not showing results

Tags: php, json

I have a pretty simple bit of code to decode a json result:

code

```
        $returnSK = returnSeoKicksLinks($s[0]);
        echo "SeoKicks: " . $returnSK;
        $seoKicks = json_decode($returnSK, true);           
        if (is_array($seoKicks) || is_object($seoKicks))
        {
            foreach ($seoKicks as $key => $val2) 
            {
                 $backlinks2 = $val2['UrlFrom'];
                 echo $backlinks2;
                 // backlink query and insertion
                 //$b = $c->query("INSERT INTO `backlinks` (`backlink_id`,`backlink_url`,`backlink_mother_url`,`backlink_date`,`backlink_from`) VALUES ('','".$backlinks2."','".$s[0]."','seokicks',NOW())");    
            }           
        }
```

The JSON results:

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "Links": [
        {
          "Anchor": "guaranteed payday loan",
          "nofollow": "1",
          "UrlTo": "http:\/\/www.site.co.uk\/"
        }
      ],
      "Index": 1,
      "IP": "67.139.134.215",
      "UrlFrom": "http:\/\/menomena.com\/?p=240",
      "DomainRank": "7"
    },
    {
      "Links": [
        {
          "nofollow": "0",
          "UrlTo": "http:\/\/www.site.co.uk\/",
          "Anchor": "Cash Till Payday Loan"
        }
      ],
      "DomainRank": "6",
      "IP": "67.222.22.156",
      "Index": 2,
      "UrlFrom": "http:\/\/www.aussi.org\/business\/financial-services\/loans\/"
    },
    {
      "DomainRank": "6",
      "UrlFrom": "http:\/\/www.loanranks.com\/improving-your-chances-of-receiving-payday-loans",
      "Index": 3,
      "IP": "173.254.28.69",
      "Links": [
        {
          "Anchor": "guaranteed payday loans",
          "nofollow": "0",
          "UrlTo": "http:\/\/www.site.co.uk\/"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Overview": {
    "domainpop": "29",
    "firstresultposition": 1,
    "totalresultsreturned": 3,
    "linkpop": "37",
    "netpop": "27",
    "ippop": "29"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the "UrlFrom" value, but it's coming up blank, is there something i am missing here?

Comment: Can you post the code that read the JSON data?

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? If so, could you mark the answer of your choice as accepted or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell PHP to look in the "Results" array, like this:

```
foreach ($seoKicks['Results'] as $key => $val2)
```

So your code would become:

```
    $seoKicks = json_decode($returnSK, true);           
    if (is_array($seoKicks) || is_object($seoKicks))
    {
        foreach ($seoKicks['Results'] as $key => $val2) 
        {
             $backlinks2 = $val2['UrlFrom'];
             echo $backlinks2;
             // backlink query and insertion
             //$b = $c->query("INSERT INTO `backlinks` (`backlink_id`,`backlink_url`,`backlink_mother_url`,`backlink_date`,`backlink_from`) VALUES ('','".$backlinks2."','".$s[0]."','seokicks',NOW())");    
        }           
    }
```

#### Some thoughts on SQL Injection

Before you uncomment the query part, please change your query to *not* concatenate values into the SQL. To avoid the risk of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding the dynamic value(s) to it.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back on the answers given?

Answer (score 0):

Without the first part of your code can not perform a test to figure out where he might be the problem. However, with this code I can print the value of `UrlFrom` field (passing the JSON in POST request):

```
$jsonPost = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decodedJson = json_decode($jsonPost);
foreach($decodedJson->Results as $key => $value) {
  var_dump($value->UrlFrom);
}
```